# Spring Security + LDAP + CustomLdapAuthoritiesPopulator + RememberMe

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap, remember-me

I have a little problem with spring security :)

**What is my goal:**
Configure LDAP auth with custom roles, fetched from database, and remember me functionality.

**What is done:**

- LDAP Auth: **OK**
- Custom roles for AD users from database: **OK**
- Remember me: **FAIL**

**My problem is:**
'Remember me' works fine, persistent_logins table created successfully, it stores tokens fine. But when user returns to web-site, spring shows 'not authorized' page.

I think it happens because 'Remember me' knows nothing about my custom roles, and fetching roles from LDAP.

**Question is:** How to tell to 'Remember me' to get roles via my **CustomLdapAuthoritiesPopulator**?

my applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389"/>
    <property name="userDn" value="cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>

<bean name="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"/>
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
            <property name="userDnPatterns">
                <list>
                    <value>uid={0},dc=example,dc=com</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="my.extra.CustomLdapAuthoritiesPopulator"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="tokenRepository"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl">
    <property name="createTableOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/403"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll()"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="permitAll()"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll()"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <security:form-login login-page='/login' login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
                         default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-url="/login?fail"/>
    <security:remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me" token-validity-seconds="14400"
                          token-repository-ref="tokenRepository"
                          user-service-ref="ldapUserService"/>

</security:http>

<security:ldap-user-service id="ldapUserService" server-ref="contextSource"
                            group-search-base="dc=example,dc=com"
                            group-search-filter="ou={0})"
                            user-search-base="dc=example,dc=com"
                            user-search-filter="uid={0}"/>
```

During debugging, when user returns, CustomLdapAuthoritiesPopulator not called.
I added code to check roles for user (on welcome page, and on custom 403 page).

```
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> roles = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
roles.forEach(System.out::println);
```

After user logs in, welcome page shows "ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN"

After user returns back, 403 page shows ""; (nothing)

Comment: Do you get an answer for the above issue ? If not, then try my answer & visit the link I have provided for more information on *Remember-Me Authentication*.

Comment: Try with new links in my answer.

Comment: I resolved the issue, a bit later will post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Spring Docs Remember-Me](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html)

> If you are using an authentication provider which doesn't use a `UserDetailsService` (for example, the **LDAP provider**) then **it won't work unless you also have a UserDetailsService bean in your application context**.

**Try adding below** in your `applicationContext.xml`:-

Add [RoleVoter](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/vote/RoleVoter.html). From Spring Docs

> Votes if any `ConfigAttribute.getAttribute()` starts with a prefix indicating that it is a role. The default prefix string is `ROLE_`, but this may be overridden to any value. It may also be set to empty, which means that essentially any attribute will be voted on. As described further below, the effect of an empty prefix may not be quite desirable.
>
> Abstains from voting if no configuration attribute commences with the role prefix. Votes to grant access if there is an exact matching `GrantedAuthority` to a `ConfigAttribute` starting with the role prefix. Votes to deny access if there is no exact matching GrantedAuthority to a ConfigAttribute starting with the role prefix.
>
> **All comparisons and prefixes are case sensitive.**

```
<bean id="roleVoter" 
    class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" p:rolePrefix="" />
```

Add [AuthenticatedVoter](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/vote/AuthenticatedVoter.html). From Soring Docs

> Votes if a `ConfigAttribute.getAttribute()` of `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` or `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` or `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` is present. This list is in order of most strict checking to least strict checking.
>
> The current Authentication will be inspected to determine if the principal has a particular level of authentication. The "FULLY" authenticated option means the user is authenticated fully (i.e. `AuthenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(Authentication)` is false and `AuthenticationTrustResolver.isRememberMe(Authentication)` is false). The `"REMEMBERED"` will grant access if the principal was either authenticated via remember-me OR is fully authenticated. The `"ANONYMOUSLY"` will grant access if the principal was authenticated via remember-me, OR anonymously, OR via full authentication.
>
> **All comparisons and prefixes are case sensitive.**

```
<bean id="authVoter" 
    class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter">               
</bean>
```

Now, configure a Spring `AccessDecisionManager` which utilizes the two voters above, in order *to determine if a user was granted the correct authority to access a resource*.

```
<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.ConsensusBased">
    <property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions" value="false" />
    <property name="decisionVoters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="roleVoter"  />
            <ref bean="authVoter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**For more details:** Visit [Spring security 3 remember-me with LDAP authentication](http://www.tikalk.com/java/spring-security-3-remember-me-ldap-authentication/)

---

**EDIT 1:**

1. [Spring Security with LDAP and Database roles](http://tiku.io/questions/2993275/spring-security-with-ldap-and-database-roles)
2. [Spring Security 3.1 - Implement UserDetailsService with Spring Data JPA](http://krams915.blogspot.in/2012/01/spring-security-31-implement_5023.html)

---

**EDIT 2:**

Below source is originally posted at [Configuring Spring Security Form Login with Remember-Me Enabled](http://blog.richardadamdean.com/?p=213).

**Create Custom RememberMeProcessingFilter:**

```
public class MyRememberMeProcessingFilter extends RememberMeProcessingFilter { 
    private myService; 

    @Override 
    protected void onSuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult) { 
        // perform some custom logic when the user has been 'remembered' & authenticated - e.g. update a login count etc 
        this.myService.doSomeCustomBusinessLogic(authResult.getName()); 

        super.onSuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, authResult); 
    } 
}
```

> `RememberMeProcessingFilter` to include any custom business logic you wish to run when a user returns to your site and is ‘remembered’ by the application.

**Don’t forget to add:**

```
<custom-authentication-provider />
```

**This makes sure that remember me is actually used as an authentication provider** - i.e. when your user returns having previously asked to be remembered, this adds remember me to the list of providers that check if the user is authenticated.

Comment: Provided link does not contains any information related 'LDAP Remember-me' implementation. And I dont know how to apply this to my configuration. Also, a lot of things marked as 'deprecated' I'm using Spring Security 3.2.4.RELEASE

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please try with this update.

Comment: RoleVoter will replace my 'use-expressions=true', I dont want it, all my controller's methods annotated with @PreAuthorize('ExpressionHere'). And I dont want to remove prefix 'ROLE_'. My main problem is: I'm using <bean class="my.extra.CustomLdapAuthoritiesPopulator"/>, after login - it will assign roles to users from my database. But remember me knows nothing about CustomLdapAuthoritiesPopulator, and when user returns back, it cant properly assign roles I think.

Comment: Have u tried *debugging your code* ? What you actually get when the user returns back & what is expected ? Have you provide custom definition for `CustomLdapAuthoritiesPopulator - getGrantedAuthorities(DirContextOperations userData, String username)` method ?

Comment: Yes, tried, I updated my question. Yes I provided custom definition of getGrantedAuthorities. In that method, code calls database for roles.

Comment: Do u get the userDetails from LDAP when user returns from remember me ?

Comment: I think you are talking about <security:ldap-user-service id="ldapUserService" server-ref="contextSource"
                                group-search-base="dc=example,dc=com"
                                group-search-filter="ou={0})"
                                user-search-base="dc=example,dc=com"
                                user-search-filter="uid={0}"/> its like userDetailsService but for LDAP. Maybe I need to set rememberMeFilter? And inside that filter, call database for roles?

Comment: Not sure, but I think you have to add `<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>` in your configuration. Have a look at [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#el-pre-post-annotations)

Comment: On remember-me, are you trying to access `LoginPage` ? *Try accessing restricted page* & check whether authentication is possible ? Check `Console Log`. Is it prints something about remember-me authentication ?

Comment: Add `<custom-authentication-provider />` to `RememberMeAuthenticationProvider`. Check [this](http://blog.richardadamdean.com/?p=213).

Comment: `<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>` already added in my web.xml and works fine. I'm trying to access restricted page. Application auto-redirect user from login page if user-remembered. Console Log shows nothing. I'll try to check your latest link a bit later today, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong solution to use

```
<security:ldap-user-service/>
```

If you want to apply custom roles from database for 'Remember me' functionality.

Still need to implement custom UserDetailsService and refer to it from remember-me section.

```
<security:http>
....
<security:remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me" token-validity-seconds="14400"
                          token-repository-ref="tokenRepository"
                          user-service-ref="rememberMeUserDetailsService"/>
</security:http>

<bean id="rememberMeUserDetailsService" class="gpb.extra.RememberMeUserDetailsService"/>
```

Its a bit tricky, but works, my database stores each username, cause it stores roles. So, I can check any user without LDAP.

```
package gpb.extra;

import gpb.database.models.User;
import gpb.database.utils.HibernateUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

public class RememberMeUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
    List<User> users = HibernateUtils.get(User.class, username, "username");
    if (users.size() == 0) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
    } else {
        User existingUser = users.get(0);
        if (!existingUser.getRoles().isEmpty()) {
            List<String> roles = Arrays.asList(existingUser.getRoles().split(","));
            roles.forEach(t -> authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(t.trim())));
        }
    }

    boolean enabled = true;
    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
            username, "password", enabled, accountNonExpired,
            credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
}
}
```

Code demonstrates main idea.

Big thanks to @OO7 for pointing me on the right way and amazing help :)

Comment: My pleasure. I am glad to know the issue has been resolved. +1 to ask such a good question.